# Python app framework create webview inside of app

Tags: python, ios, webview, uiwebview, kivy

I need to embed a webview inside my kivy app or with some other python app framework that supports this for both android and IOS. I am looking to also save cookies for log in so users do not have to log in more than once. Is this possible or should I look for another way to accomplish this? Thanks for any responses in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is no "universal" method to do this. It should however still be possible. There unfortunately isn't a kivy "native" method either.

**Android:**

For android you can use [webview-android](https://pypi.org/project/webview-android/):

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from webview import WebView
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

Builder.load_string("""
<MyWebView>
    MDFlatButton:
        text: "Push"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
        on_press: root.Push()
""")

class MyWebView(MDScreen):
    def Push(self):
        WebView("https://www.google.com")


class MyWebApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return MyWebView()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyWebApp().run()
```

Furthermore, you can use [jnius](https://pypi.org/project/jnius/) to access the java classes, that would do this normally:

```
import kivy                                                                                     
from kivy.app import App                                                                        
from kivy.lang import Builder                                                                   
from kivy.utils import platform                                                                 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget                                                              
from kivy.clock import Clock                                                                    
from jnius import autoclass                                                                     
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread                                                   
                                                                                                
WebView = autoclass('android.webkit.WebView')                                                   
WebViewClient = autoclass('android.webkit.WebViewClient')                                       
activity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity                              
                                                                                                
class Wv(Widget):                                                                               
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):                                                               
        super(Wv, self).__init__(**kwargs)                                                      
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_webview, 0)                                             
                                                                                                
    @run_on_ui_thread                                                                           
    def create_webview(self, *args):                                                            
        webview = WebView(activity)                                                             
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(True)                                        
        wvc = WebViewClient();                                                                  
        webview.setWebViewClient(wvc);                                                          
        activity.setContentView(webview)                                                        
        webview.loadUrl('http://www.google.com')
                                                                                                
class ServiceApp(App):                                                                          
    def build(self):                                                                            
        return Wv()                                                                             
                                                                                                
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                      
    ServiceApp().run()
```

**iOS**:

Unfortunately I don't own an iOS device, so I can not test any of this.

The [kivy-ios](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios/blob/d662d3dfd4acc7f39d7e2ebb4e1212f48eb49cce/recipes/ios/src/ios.pyx#L48-L52) module seems to contain methods for accomplishing this:

```
import ios
url = "http://www.google.com"
ios.IOSWebView().open(url, width, height)
```

Another solution would be to use [pyobjus](https://github.com/kivy/pyobjus) to access the Objective-C classes, that would normally implement the webview on iOS. I don't want to paste untested code, so I suggest you check out Michael Galaxy and Julez' answers on the bottom of [this google group](https://groups.google.com/g/kivy-users/c/9sH0y3KxCuU).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems like kivy-ios only supports macs and I am using a windows machine for development. Pyobjus was giving me issues with installation and was not working.

Comment: I see... Take note, that neither version will work on your desktop though. The android versions require the java classes to be present. That obviously is not the case on your windows machine. According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/8f2x31/webview_on_kivyios/) reddit post however, the kivy-ios version should work on an iOS device.

Comment: @NameKhan72 Could you please suggest webview for desktop app using kivymd?